# How do I add customer attribute personalization to my online optimization asset markup in Interaction Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, action, interaction

I have been trying to work out a way of reading the customer attributes for an individual in order to create a personalized message. I'm assuming I'm looking to tdo this by adding some syntax in the html markup asset for my online optimization action in interaction studio but so far {customerAttribute} {aep.customerAttribute} {{cutomerAttribute}} etc doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the syntax used here as an example work at all for you?

**Visitor Meta Data**

```
Customer ID:    ${visitorMetaData.customerId}
Visitor Creation Date: ${visitorMetaData.creationDate}
Recognized: [#if visitorMetaData.recognized]YES[/#if][#if visitorMetaData.recognized != true]NO[/#if]
```

I haven't used this myself but I have seen some documentation that said the interaction studio assets were compatible with FreeMarker but had never had a chance to try it.